# Empty Positional Argument when using /bin/bash -c <script>

Tags: bash

I'm trying to launch a script with `/bin/bash -c` with positional arguments but can't figure out the following issue:

Suppose I have test.sh as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $0
echo $1
```

```
> ./test.sh a
./test.sh
a

> /bin/bash -c ./test.sh a
./test.sh
```

Why does the second one return an empty position argument for $1? Based on the man page:

```
   -c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.  If there are arguments after the command_string, the first argument is assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional
             parameters.  The assignment to $0 sets the name of the shell, which is used in warning and error messages.
```

It seems like "a" should be assigned to $0 at least, which is not what I saw. `/bin/bash -c 'echo $0' a` works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string after `-c` acts like a miniature script, and the arguments after that are passed to it as `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, etc. For example:

```
$ bash -c 'echo "\$0=$0, \$1=$1, \$2=$2"' zero one two
$0=zero, $1=one, $2=two
```

(Note: it's important that the mini-script is in single-quotes; without them the references to `$0` would be expanded by your interactive shell before they even get passed to the `bash -c` command.)

In your case, the mini-script runs another script (`./test.sh`), but doesn't pass on the arguments. If you wanted to pass them on, you'd do something like this:

```
$ bash -c './test.sh "$1" "$2"' zero one two
./test.sh
one
```

If the script had bothered to print its `$2` here, it would've gotten "two". It doesn't help to pass on `$0`, because for a real script that's automatically set to the actual command used to run the script.

Answer (score 1):

> bash [long-opt] [-abefhkmnptuvxdBCDHP] [-o option] [-O shopt_option]
>   **-c string** [argument ...]

`-c` supposed to be followed by a string, so you may quote `./test.sh a` like:

```
$ /bin/bash -c "./test.sh a"
./test.sh
a
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-c` option does not collect **all** following arguments of the bash command, but just uses the first non-option argument, which in your case is the one immediately following it. I don't see why you want to use `-c` here. I would write your command as

```
/bin/bash test.sh a
```

Since in this case, no PATH search is involved, you can also omit the `./` part. In fact, `test.sh` doesn't even need to be executable here.